# To change text color and background color for an annotated in TextClickableText after it is clicked

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I would like to change the text color and the background color of an annotated clickable text.

I looked into the examples for clickable text in google developer but did not find anything related to this.

```
ClickableText(
    text = annotatedText,
    onClick = { offset ->
        // We check if there is an *URL* annotation attached to the text
        // at the clicked position
        annotatedText.getStringAnnotations(tag = "URL", start = offset,
                                                end = offset)
            .firstOrNull()?.let { annotation ->
                // To change the text color when it is clicked <<<<<<<<<<<<< here
            }
    }
)
```

What I want to do is to highlight the word the user has clicked.

For example:

[image]

If the user clicks the first letter "Text", it would look like the following.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't think this is very efficient, this code should do the trick:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun SelectableText(
    annotatedText: AnnotatedString,
    onTextClicked: (Int) -> Unit,
) {
    ClickableText(
        text = annotatedText,
        onClick = { offset ->
            annotatedText.spanStyles.indexOfFirst {
                it.start <= offset && offset <= it.end
            }.takeIf { it != -1 }?.also {
                onTextClicked(it)
            }
        }
    )
}

@Composable
fun View() {
    var annotatedText by remember {
        mutableStateOf(AnnotatedString("Test", listOf(AnnotatedString.Range(SpanStyle(), 0, 4))))
    }

    SelectableText(annotatedText, onTextClicked = {
        val styles = annotatedText.spanStyles.toMutableList()
        styles[it] = styles[it].copy(SpanStyle(background = Color.Cyan))
        annotatedText = AnnotatedString(annotatedText.text, styles, annotatedText.paragraphStyles)
    })
}
```

A custom `SelectableText` `@Composable` is created, with a callback which is called when a span is clicked. I am using spans and not annotations because this is where the style is defined.

When clicked, the parent `@Composable` (here, `View`) reacts to the event, grabs a copy of the `spanStyles` and modifies the one which was clicked. Then it updates the `annotatedText`. (You might want to "turn off" the selection on the rest of spans.)